# Pop up activity closes on touch event in some phones

Tags: android, window-managers

I have a strange problem. im developing an app which overlays the incoming call screen. I have achieved displaying the popup window and everything works fine also i can access the receive and disconnect call controls below the pop up window on my galaxy s2.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

i've set the flags on my window to achieve the desired effect. But the while running the same code on  galaxy s3/note 2. whenever i touch the screen anywhere my activity disappears! i have written methods to perform different actions on if the call is picked up or dropped. But i can never call those methods as the activity destroys itself just upon touch at any point of the screen.

Comment: did you try using setCancelable(false) for your popup window ?

Comment: yes ive tried that too and more over setCancellable(false) requires >= API11 call which wouldnt be an option.